# How the constructor and destructor work?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(){
        cout <<"C ";
    }
    ~Foo(){
        cout <<"D ";
    }
};

void func(){
    Foo* p = new Foo;
    p = NULL;
}

int main(){
    Foo a;
    for (int i=0; i<1; i++){
        Foo b;
        if (true){
            Foo c;
        }
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For this question, the output is C C C D C D D, and if I delete the func() in the main function, the output become C C C D D D, I understand the first 3 C where it come from, but I don't understand the remaining, please explain it, thanks.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<1; i++)` essentially executes it's block once, so does `if(true)`. If you want to define a scope, you can simply use a pair of braces (`{ }`). You do not need to use them in the context of a flow control statement, You could simply do `int main(){ Foo a; { Foo b; { Foo c; } func(); } return 0; }`

Comment: Stepping through this with a debugger might help...

Comment: `p = NULL;` doesn't actually destroy the object. The `new Foo` object is leaked. This line should read `delete p;`.

Comment: It seems you are confused about what a destructor does and how object life time work. This is pretty fundamental stuff for c++, best covered by a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If you'd add some debug message, you'd notice that the ctors are for abcp and dtors for cba in the order of exiting scope. P leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. C - a is constructed
2. C - b is constructed
3. C - c is constructed
4. D - c is desctructed becouse you leave the scope
5. C - an object Foo is dynamically allocated and pointed to by p, but since it is dynamically allocated, and never deleted, it's never destructed.
6. D - b is destructed
7. D - a is destructed

Answer (score 3):

The scope of the object `a` is the scope of the outer code block of the function main. It is the first object that is created and the last object that is deleted.

```
int main(){
    Foo a;
    // ...
    return 0;
}

C C C D C D D
|           |
a           a
```

Then in the for loop that has only one iteration there is created the object `b` that is deleted after the first iteration of the loop

```
for (int i=0; i<1; i++){
    Foo b;
    // ...
}

C C C D C D D
| |       | |
a b       b a
```

Then in the block scope of the statement if

```
    if (true){
        Foo c;
    }
```

there is created and deleted the object `c`

```
C C C D C D D
| | | |   | |
a b c c   b a
```

After that the function `func` is called

```
func();
```

Inside the function there is created an unnamed object using the operator new and pointed to by the pointer `p`.

```
void func(){
    Foo* p = new Foo;
    p = NULL;
}

C C C D C D D
| | | | | | |
a b c c p b a
```

This object is not deleted because the operator delete is not called for this object. So there is a memory leak.

That is all.

Answer (score 1):

There order would be for C C C D C D D:

1. C - Construct A
2. C - Construct B
3. C - Construct C
4. D - Destruct C
5. C - Construct p (in func)
6. D - Destruct B
7. D - Destruct A

// memleak for p (in func)

Answer (score 0):

When the `func();` call is included, the steps taken are:

```
Foo a; -> C

Foo b; -> C

Foo c; -> C

Left the scope of Foo c -> D

func(); call ->
    new Foo; -> C

Finished func() call, left the scope of Foo b -> D

Left the scope of Foo a -> D
```

Note that the Foo object created in func() is never destructured, meaning you have a memory leak.